# How to remove an old instance of an image and leave the newly placed version in a repeating code

Tags: javascript, image, repeat

In my project, I am trying to place "enemies" in random spots on the canvas I am working with. I have got that part down, but I am trying to remove the older instance of the image "enemies" and only have the re-randomized enemy on screen.
Here is the code for the "enemy"

```
function enemies(){
   var movementX= Randomizer.nextInt(midW,width-50);
   var movementY= Randomizer.nextInt(midH,0);
   var enemyMove= new WebImage("https://codehs.com/uploads/2d57d03e4ed3a0aaa0bc43f4cb37509b");
   enemyMove.setSize(50,50);
   enemyMove.setPosition(movementX,movementY);
   add(enemyMove);
```

I have this program running every 9 seconds to place another enemy in a different location than the last. I would like to remove the old instance of this image each time the program executes so only the newly positioned "enemy" is on screen. It currently just places "enemies" all over the screen and does not remove the previous instance. If possible I would appreciate any insight into how to remove the old instances of the code running. I have tried putting `if(enemyMove == 2){ remove(enemyMove);` after `add(enemyMove);` to see if would remove one instance of `enemyMove` from the screen once two images were present but that did nothing. I would really appreciate any feedback on how this would work

Answer (score 0):

You should download the image once during a setup phase and either keep the image in some global variable for reuse or pass it as a function argument containing the main loop.

Comment: Ok I kind of get that, but could I make a function that limits the number of images on the screen, using the If statement I mentioned before if it is calling  on the global variable enemyMove rather than the local variable within the function enemies

Comment: Same story, you need to keep track of your objects in order to remove them. You should have a list of enemies and associated images and other info that allows you to redraw them. In fact, when you move an enemy, you are not adding it. That's confusing from a programmatic point of view. It will soon become very messy. If you keep a refence to the images, you could simply change the position of the images instead of creating new ones.